# First 20 values that are true

Tags: python-3.x

```
for n in range(561,1000):
if n is not isprime2(n) and isprimelike(n):
    print(n,isprimelike(n))
```

I want my function to print the first 20 values that satisfy this condition instead of printing the whole range.  Like once it sees 20 values that make this condition true, stop.

Comment: `n is not isprime2(n)` looks wierd to me. do you mean `if not isprime2(n) and isprimelike(n):` ? (please fix indentation)

Answer (score 2):

First, I'm assuming that this is a typo: `if n is not isprime2(n) and isprimelike(n)` makes no sense. You want `if not isprime2(n) and isprimelike(n)`

To solve this, I would create a generator comprehension with a condition out of your loop:

```
(n for n in range(561,1000) if not isprime2(n) and isprimelike(n))
```

(you don't need to print `isprimelike` since it is `True` in your case, we filtered `False` values out)

then intergrate it to loop 20 times and get the 20 first iterations, in one line:

```
[next(n for n in range(561,1000) if not isprime2(n) and isprimelike(n)) for _ in range(20)]
```

or (courtesy to Jon), using `itertools.islice` which is better if there aren't enough values (solution above throws `StopIteration` in that case)

```
list(itertools.islice((n for n in range(561,1000) if not isprime2(n) and isprimelike(n)),20))
```

Comment: If `isprimelike` is expensive - might only want to calculate it once

Comment: @JonClements True. but `isprimelike` is in fact always True at this point. No need to output it.

Comment: And to take the first 20... `for n in islice(your_gen_exp, 20): print(n)`... (Or `list(islice(genexp, 20))`

Comment: Heck... `list(islice((n for n in range(561, 1000) if not isprime2(n) and isprimelike(n)), 20)`

Comment: yeah exactly same here. Telepathy as always :)

Answer (score 1):

Of course there is a simpler method of completing this task, an easy-on-the-eye way to do this is to simply create a variable that stores the amount of prints.

I.E

```
AoPrints = 0 # Amount of Prints
for n in range(561,1000):
  if n is not isprime2(n) and isprimelike(n): # NOTE: the first condition here does not look accurate
    print(n,isprimelike(n))
    AoPrints = AoPrints+1
    if AoPrints > 20:
      break # Exit the for-loop
```